# Does an mx:Window component have it's own applicationComplete?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, components, air

I'm working on an app that, from the Main.mxml, opens one or many Window.mxml instances. When it's done I want all windows to be chromeless so the custom controls need to work.

In Main I've added `applicationComplete="init();"` so the init function gets ran, which contains clickhandlers, which makes the buttons work.
However, this way of running an init function doesn't seem to be valid for an mx:Window.

I can *cheat* by not using a clickhandler for the minimize and close buttons with a `click="this.minimize();"`, but I don't know of a way like this to make the move work because it's a MOUSE_DOWN event.

Question 1:
Is there a way to have such an init function in an mx:Window?

Question 2:
What's a good way to make the buttons on the Window instances all work?

ps. If you think question 2 needs a separate post please let me know, they're so closely related and seemingly simple I couldn't decide.

Example code:
Main.mxml - http://pastebin.com/0HHVpkb8
Window.mxml - http://pastebin.com/g5TWuLYk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window doesn't have an applicationComplete event, but it does have windowComplete event. Perhaps that would work for you. There is a list if Window events [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Window.html#eventSummary).